# Storing/deleting/adding images to Java web application

Tags: java, image, metadata

In my application I want users to be able to add and delete images, at the moment I have my images stored in an `images` folder and they are deleted using the following code.

```
if(delete != null){
  for (int i = 0; i < delete.length; i++){
    imagePath = ctx.getRealPath("WebContent/"+delete[i]);
    try{
      file = new File(imagePath);
      file.delete();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

However it is only deleting the image in the `.metadata` folder but it is not deleting the image from my `images` folder, what is the proper way to deal with this situation and where should the images all be deleted from?

Comment: Use the same path where you save the files. By the way, the path should be **external** to your web application server.

Comment: At the moment my images are contained in `WebContent/images` should I just delete the image from there or should I delete from the `.metadata` folder as well?

Comment: Again, you should use a path external to your web application server. This means, it should be **outside** of your web application path and **outside** of your web application server, like */path/ouside/from/server/*.

Comment: I have tried doing this but I am having trouble as Chrome is giving me an error `Not allowed to load local resource`. How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you displaying the images after saving them?

Comment: Just with `src=filePath` in relation to the current page.